# xls created by ReportingService encoding issue when returned in HtmlResponseMessage in a WebApiCall

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, encoding, xls

I'm having problem to export a **xls** file. It seems like an encoding problem because of its result:

[image]

I already tried to specify different encodes (UTF-8, UTF-16) but none seems to work. We use the **Reporting Services** to create the xls file and the xls file is correct when we just save in the directory.

PS: the xls file has images.

---

The response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true  
Cache-Control:no-cache  
Connection:keep-alive  
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=Test.xls  
Content-Length:901056  
**Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel**  
Date:Thu, 12 May 2016 11:55:48 GMT  
Expires:-1  
Pragma:no-cache  
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5  
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

---

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostExport()
    {
        var reportingServiceExtractor = new ReportingServiceExtractor(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reporting.services.name.cart"], FormatExtractor.Excel);
        var userInfo = _operationServices.userInfo();

        var user = _userRepo.GetUserRolesByEmail(userInfo.email);

        var parameters = new List<ParameterValue>
        {
            new ParameterValue
            {
                Name = "User",
                Value = user.Id.ToString()
            }
        };

        string mimeType = null;
        string encoding = null;

        var extract = reportingServiceExtractor.Extract(parameters, out mimeType, out encoding);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(extract);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
        result.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.xls");
        result.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", encoding);

        return result;
    }
```

---

```
    public Stream Extract(ICollection<ParameterValue> parameterValues, out string mimeType, out string encoding)
    {
        using (var reportExecutionServiceSoapClient = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient())
        {
            reportExecutionServiceSoapClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = _credentials;
            reportExecutionServiceSoapClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
                TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

            byte[] result = null;
            string reportPath = $"/{_reportName}";
            string format = _formatExtractor.ToString();

            const string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

            var execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
            var execHeader = new ServerInfoHeader();

            try
            {
                var executionHeader = reportExecutionServiceSoapClient.LoadReport(null, reportPath, null, out execHeader,
                out execInfo);


                reportExecutionServiceSoapClient.SetExecutionParameters(executionHeader, null, parameterValues.ToArray(),
                    "en-us", out execInfo);

                string extension;
                Warning[] warnings = null;
                string[] streamIDs = null;

                reportExecutionServiceSoapClient.Render(executionHeader, null, format, devInfo,
                    out result, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"{ex}");
                throw;
            }
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(result.Length);
            stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            stream.Position = 0;

            return stream;
        }
```